# How to Edit projections in external editor with Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

I wonder is it possible to export projections to external editor (Gimp, Krita, Photoshop), edit it and after editing is done changes to be applied on models texture.

That option is available in 3DCoat via Edit → Edit Projections in ext. Editor After user selects that option selected 2D editor will open psd file of projection that is currently on 3DCoat camera view.

Is there similar option or addon in Blender 2.8+?

Here is my question/explanation in a form of a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/9j3j-q97FgU).

Comment: No Ray Mairlot. But tnx for an answer. In short, I will try to make YouTube video with workflow in 3DCoat. Maybe it will be easier for me to explain what do I try to accomplish.

Comment: Here is my explanation in form of video.
https://youtu.be/9j3j-q97FgU

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I know. You are absolutely right. I think that it is sufficient what I had already said. The video is there just for further explanation.

Comment: Any ideas for solving this question?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqnF3LCm-cA. It was in Blender for a while, starting from 2.7x versions.